# Adjusting included js scripts in Magento in page.xml

Tags: javascript, xml, magento

I am trying to clean out some dead js includes, but am not having any luck. I have deleted the lines from `page.xml`, for example:

```
<action method="addJs"><script>custom/custom.js</script></action>
```

And have checked `local.xml` as well to ensure the lines are not there. But the page is still showing these files included and being loaded (I have not deleted the actual js files yet). I am not sure if I need to delete references in other places? If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated. Please let me know if I can provide anything else to help. Thanks!

Comment: these scripts shows in every page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clear your Cache and check again.. you can do this via admin panel

Comment: Man it was a long day yesterday haha. Was definitely a cache issue, thanks

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript can be included on any page from literally any Layout XML file (provided that Layout XML file is being parsed by Magento). It can also be included in any template file.

Magento has a very complicated layout/theme hierarchy with tons of files, some of them parsed and rendered, most of them not parsed or rendered.

It makes it difficult to try to guess or intuit where/how a given piece of HTML is being rendered, so in situations like this I usually search for references to the file in the design folder:

1. `cd /magento/document/root`
2. `grep -Ri 'custom.js' app/design`

Assuming you're on Linux (or most other Unix-like operating systems), this should list every Layout XML file (or phtml template) referencing that dead JS file (custom.js). Then you just go to those files and remove the offending XML nodes (or script elements).

Comment: Good to know. It ended up being a caching issue but this is useful to have for future reference, thanks